# Managing resources for packaging as jar

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io, resources

I am currently reading files from a resource folder declared as source folder in eclipse.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResource("/textures/" + fileName));
```

and

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(OBJFileLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/objs/" + objFileName + ".obj")));
```

This is good if I want to package my resources into the jar. But it wouldn't work if I also wanted to write to the files.

I could just access them placing them outside my buildpath, which would be okay in eclipse but very ugly when having it along my jar. As i think there is no way of writing to a JAR file (at least no "clean" one), I will have to place my resources outside.

How can I read and write text files and image files while keeping my folder structure (sorting my assets in sub folder) which works in my IDE and also with a JAR?

Comment: Can you use maven? If yes, you simply have to put the resources under src/main/resources and all the folder content will be in the jar root folder

Comment: That results in the same as putting my resources in folder and declaring it as source folder in eclipse. I then still can't write to them when outside of my IDE.

Comment: With maven you will have the same result outside the IDE with maven command line, perhaps I did not understand your question if this is not the case

Comment: I want to write to files after compilation and packaging into a jar file but also want them to be in the default location of my resources so I can load them.